# Why 'all' function works faster with list than generator?

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to realize some performace subtleties of Python.
One of them is using iterators and generators in built-in functions like all, any, max, etc.

For example, we have a list of integers:

```py
arr: list[int] = list(range(10_000))
```

Then we measure time of these two variants:

```py
all(isinstance(x, int) for x in arr)
```

```py
all([isinstance(x, int) for x in arr])
```

I thought that the first variant will be faster because it doesn't take up a memory to create an array. But I get respectively:

```
1.04 ms ± 79.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

```
915 µs ± 50.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Why is the second one faster?

I tried to disassemble, the second one uses a little less instructions. Is this the case?

```
In [11]: def f():
    ...:     return all(isinstance(x, int) for x in arr)
    ...: 

In [12]: def g():
    ...:     return all([isinstance(x, int) for x in arr])
    ...: 

In [13]: from dis import dis

In [14]: dis(f)

...

Disassembly of <code object <genexpr> at 0x7f459e2537e0, file "<ipython-input-11-973ce3497c83>", line 2>:
              0 GEN_START                0

  2           2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 22)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (isinstance)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (int)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             16 YIELD_VALUE
             18 POP_TOP
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2 (to 4)
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE

In [15]: dis(g)

...

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x7f459ebf92c0, file "<ipython-input-12-d4d6130487f9>", line 2>:
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 7 (to 20)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (isinstance)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (int)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             16 LIST_APPEND              2
             18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2 (to 4)
        >>   20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: I suspect if you increase the number of integers to something like 1 million the generator would perform better. It's a relatively small list

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, you are right!

43.6 ms VS 54.2 ms for 1 million

Comment: Building the list uses more resources, but the resulting list can be iterated over faster. You need a very large list before it's worth spending the time to build the faster list.